# React-datepicker selected date format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime, react-datepicker

The current date format: 2021-04-30T23:00:00.000Z

Things tried but not worked
`(new Date(startDate)`
`new Date(startDate).toLocaleDateString()`

The error

```
RangeError: Invalid time value

var originalDate = toDate(dirtyDate);
  
  if (!isValid(originalDate)) {
   throw new RangeError('Invalid time value');
    } // Convert the date in system timezone to the same date in UTC+00:00 timezone.
     // This ensures that when UTC functions will be implemented, locales will be compatible with them.
     // See an issue about UTC functions: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/376
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an `ISO-8601` date representation, you can convert this by passing it into the `Date` constructor and call functions like `getURChours()` on the object

```js
let date = new Date('2021-04-30T23:00:00.000Z');
console.log(date.getUTCHours()); // Hours
console.log(date.getUTCMinutes()); // Minutes
console.log(date.getUTCSeconds()); // Seconds
```